# Why did Matuzak mention about "Potomac River"?

Tags: timecop

In time travel movie *Timecop (1994)*, Max Walker wants to haul Senator Aaron McComb who is the reason
behind his partner's death. He tells his leader Matuzak about his
decision to haul Senator Aaron McComb.

> Max Walker: This one is mine.
>
> Matuzak: Not unless I say it is. The son of a bitch is a presidential 
>   candidate. If you haul him in, you better have enough evidence  to
>   plug up the **Potomac River**.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Potomac runs by Washington D.C.  (It used to run *through* D.C., until the south bank was returned to Virginia.)  It is frequently referred to metonymously as representing the U.S. federal government.  It's also quite a broad river near its mouth, and hence it would be very difficult to dam.

So it means, *If you're going to arrest this guy, all of official Washington is going to become involved, and your case had better be strong enough to withstand that level of scrutiny.*

Comment: You might also want to mention the symbology of a *torrent of questions* being asked.

Comment: https://www.tripsavvy.com/washington-dc-potomac-river-waterfront-1038693